# Can't play audio on Android - Sencha Touch SDK tools 2.0.0

Tags: android, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, html5-audio

I heard that Android devices do not play some audio files in html5 (for example they support mp3 but do not play files created with help of some standart soft: [the link](http://www.brianhadaway.com/html5-audio-support-on-android-devices/)).

I tried different variants, but no one worked for me.

E.g. the standart example from [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Audio):

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title : 'Ext.Audio'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: function() {
                    var container = this.getParent().getParent(),
                        // use ComponentQuery to get the audio component (using its xtype)
                        audio = container.down('audio');

                    audio.toggle();
                    this.setText(audio.isPlaying() ? 'Pause' : 'Play');
                }
            },
            items: [
                { text: 'Play', flex: 1 }
            ]
        },
        {
            html: 'Hidden audio!',
            styleHtmlContent: true
        },
        {
            xtype : 'audio',
            hidden: true,
            url   : 'touch/examples/audio/crash.mp3'
        }
    ]
});
```

And audio in html:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="resources/sound/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Can't play sound on your device.
</audio>
```

When I debug my application with help of the Chrome browser I hear the sound, but I do not hear it on a real device (Android 2.3.5).

In case of the html variant I see that a slider twitches and immediately stay at the end of a progress bar. In case of the 'play' button everything works normally (graphics, play/pause) except the sound that is missing.

I did not find any special Android permission option for sound, so, I think the permissions are not the reason.

**The question**. Am I wrong and is it possible to play any mp3 audio? What is the easiest work around?

Comment: You could have a problem either with the mp3 file itself, or with the html5, so it would be good to check the two separately.  Load the file into the music library on the device and see if it will play, or try the web page with an audio file already proven to play locally.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have already tested a web page on the Android device in 2 different browsers. The player (audio tag) works normally. So, is it a problem of the Sencha Touch product?

Comment: You haven't specified what the single variable is between the working and non-working cases.  If you have more than one variable, you don't have a meaningful test.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If I understand you correctly the variable is using of Sencha Touch with it's html layout (panel) or using something else. At this moment I realized that Sencha's html layout implementation has the bug. Or may be it uses some obsolete lib. But I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried the file locally on the Sencha?  Have you tried someone else's web page on it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It works via the Internet! It doesn't work with a relative local URL. It's strange that it works normally with the local URL on my pc (web browser + local web server).

Comment: Whatever web server you are testing against might be setting a proper mime type on the audio file (itself), while your local test web server might not.  Your PC browser as a client might not care.  Or it could be that your file itself is marginally bad.  Can you test with the same file as on the web site?

Comment: Yes, the same file from a website URL plays in sencha layout normally (such as http://site.com/1.mp3). I can't use local URL (for example, "resources/sound/1.mp3"). Both cases are for a real Android device.

Comment: That doesn't rule out the mime type the web server is giving the file being an issue, since you are still getting the file off the remote web server.  You might also check if you can link to something else locally, like another html file, just to check that relative links are working.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The path is correct. I can see an image (by settings the src attribute of an img tag). But I can't hear the sound on a near path.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So, the file does play from an external website but doesn't play locally. We have access to another files (pictures) on the same path.

Comment: If the same file that worked remotely does not work on the local server, and a picture does work on the local server, I think it's time to check the mime type concern.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I removed the Content-Type from a web server response (it was 'audio/mpeg'). However the sound remained playable from http server. I expected it was not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And if I remove 'Content-Length' the sound become not playable from web server. But the player behaviour is different in compare to the player behavior of a local file: it case of remote file it does not start to play, but in case of the local file it starts, a slider twitches and immediately stop (without any sound).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Am I understand correctly that it means probably Content-Type (mime) is not the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencha Touch Audio only works in the Android / Chrome browser, not on the device. One solution is to wrap your app with [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) and use the [Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) object for audio. A lot of bother but mostly it works.